# Multiple member constexpr struct initialization based on a loop

Tags: c++, struct, constructor, constexpr

[Initial Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62903653/multiple-member-constexpr-struc-initialization)

I am trying to learn `constexpr`. I was stuck initially trying to initialize the `struct` but that was quickly answered. Now that I am looking at the result it seems like the `struct` is initialized to `0` and then is constant. I want the `primeValue` array to be correctly initialized with prime numbers. How do I initialize the `struct` correctly? Feel free to make any changes to the code.

https://godbolt.org/z/x9WsqP

Comment: Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please [edit] your question to include your [mcve] inside the question itself.

Comment: After `size_t n = 0;` you have the condition `n < prime_array_size` and then `PrimeData::primeValue[n] = ...` but `n` does never change. That seems very wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has two errors:

1. Your initialization is incorrect: in `for (auto b : PrimeData::isPrime)`, `b` is a local bool variable and `b = true` simply overwrites the local variable. To update the original data, you must use `auto& b : PrimeData::isPrime` (and the same applies to the `primeValue` initialization loop, although since you are initializing them to 0 the whole thing is unnecessary).
2. You forgot to increment `n` in the last loop. Change it to `PrimeData::primeValue[n++] = static_cast<unsigned>(p);`.

https://godbolt.org/z/YGjKch

Comment: Thank you! I was so lost on trying to get constexpr working that I forgot to increment n. It would have taken more time to fix the boolean reference,